# SharePoint REST API call with more than 500 rows

Tags: 2013, javascript, rest, ajax

I have an AJAX call querying the SharePoint REST API which will return more than 500 rows:

```
$.ajax(
        {
             url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/search/query?querytext='Department:"
                    + "*'&selectproperties='Department'&sourceid='B09A7990-05EA-4AF9-81EF-EDFAB16C4E31'&sortlist='Department:ascending'&rowlimit=500",
                method: "GET",
                headers: {
                    "accept": "application/xml",
                },
                success: onSuccess,
                error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                    alert(xhr.status);
                    alert(thrownError);
                }
            }
        );
```

The REST API has a 500 row limit, so I cannot increase the `rowlimit` variable in the `url`.

In my onSuccess function, I'm trying to read the total rows to see if I need to query again for more rows:

```
onSuccess = function (data) {
    var rows = data.d.postquery.PrimaryQueryResult.RelevantResults.TotalRows;
....
```

This throws an exception that `postquery` does not exist, however.

How can I grab the TotalRows and query the REST API for additional rows?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See if these paths to the row count variables work:

```
data.d.query.PrimaryQueryResult.RelevantResults.RowCount

data.d.query.PrimaryQueryResult.RelevantResults.TotalRows
```

If you have specific questions about the object model, I find that the best first point of reference is to look at the returned xml or json using web developer tools and looking at the returned object graph.

Comment: Both of these throw an error saying `query` is not defined. If I change the response type to `application/json`, both of those DO work... `RowCount` gives me 500, the total rows in the current response, not the total rows for the query, `TotalRows` does give me that though (again, with the json response, not the xml). I don't want the response in json though.

Comment: @FalakMahmood Not sure what you mean. That resides under the `query` object and that's not defined under the XML response. `TotalRows` already gives me what I want, but only with a json response.

Comment: I don't have access to a 2013 farm for testing at the moment, but if you use the web developer tools in IE or Chrome, you can see the response and get an idea of the object model.

Comment: @tyshock Brilliant! I totally forgot about that, I can see the TotalRows property hiding in the XML. If you'd like to add that to your answer, I will accept it.

Comment: Though I AM still trying to figure out how to re-query starting at the 500th row.

Comment: And for reference... to get TotalRows in the xml response: `var rows = $(data).find("d\\:TotalRows").first().text();`

Comment: For re-querying starting from the 500th row, you can use the `startrow` parameter. Eg: `/_api/search/query?querytext='*'&startrow=500'`

Answer (score 12):

Here is an example that demonstrates how to  query *all* search results using SharePoint 2013 Search REST API:

```
function search(webUrl,queryText,rowLimit,startRow,allResults)
{
    var allResults = allResults || [];
    var url = webUrl + "/_api/search/query?querytext='" + queryText + "'&rowlimit=" + rowLimit + "'&startrow=" + startRow;
    return $.getJSON(url).then(function(data) {
           var relevantResults = data.PrimaryQueryResult.RelevantResults;
           allResults = allResults.concat(relevantResults.Table.Rows);
           if (relevantResults.TotalRows > startRow + relevantResults.RowCount) {
               return search(webUrl,queryText,rowLimit,startRow+relevantResults.RowCount,allResults);
           }    
           return allResults;
    });
}
```

Key points:

- `StartRow` query parameter is used to specify *next*  paged search results

**Usage**

```
search(_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl,'sharepoint',100,0)
  .done(function(results){
       for(var i = 0;i < results.length;i++){
           console.log(results[i].Cells[3].Value);
       }
   });
```

Comment: top notch. Thanks a bunch

Answer (score 4):

You can raise the  `MaxRowLimit` property of your Search service application (Only with On-Prem SharePoint installation) using PowerShell to overcome this limitation. But remember, it will affect the perform though.

Answer (score 3):

Try these.

`data.d.query.PrimaryQueryResult.RelevantResults.TotalRows`

`data.d.query.PrimaryQueryResult.RelevantResults.TotalRowsIncludingDuplicates`

I tested on O365.