# Display account info in SharePoint web part

Tags: sharepoint-server, development, 2016, jsom

can we get the user profile details in web part using JSOM

I am looking for a profile web part to show this info

- user profile image
- user email
- user job title
- user extension

any help would be appreciated

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to call `getUserProfile` from `sp.js` script

**Add this script in script editor web part**

```
<script type="text/ecmascript">
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(getUserProfile, "sp.js");
function getUserProfile(){
    var userID= _spPageContextInfo.userId;
    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var web = clientContext.get_web();
    var userInfoList = web.get_siteUserInfoList();
    var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
    camlQuery.set_viewXml("<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='ID'/><Value Type='Number'>" + userID + "</Value></Eq></Where></Query><RowLimit>1</RowLimit></View>");
    this.collListItem = userInfoList.getItems(camlQuery);
    clientContext.load(collListItem);
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded),Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
}
function onQuerySucceeded(sender, args){
    var item = collListItem.itemAt(0);   
    var userName =  item.get_fieldValues().UserName;
    var displayName= item.get_fieldValues().Title;
    var email= item.get_fieldValues().EMail;
    var html="";
    if(userName!=null){
        html+="<img src='/_layouts/15/userphoto.aspx?size=S&username=" + userName + "'/>";      
    }
    if(displayName!=null){
        html+="<p><span>Name:"+ displayName+"</span></p>";      
    } 
    if(email!=null){
        html+="<p><span>Email: "+ email+"</span></p>";       
    }   
    var profileDiv = document.getElementById("CurrentUserProfile");
    profileDiv.innerHTML = html;     
}
function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
    //alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
</script>
<div id="CurrentUserProfile">   
<div>
```

[Script Ref](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/09148f2f-e08e-47e9-9434-08c59810b44e/how-to-display-the-current-users-profile-properties-as-a-web-part-in-share-point-2013-online?forum=sharepointdevelopment)

---

**To get User Profile Pic**

```
var obj = item.get_fieldValues().Picture;
```

**To Get email**

```
var obj = item.get_fieldValues().Email;
```

**To get the job title**

```
var obj = item.get_fieldValues().JobTitle;
```

**To get Phone**

```
var obj = item.get_fieldValues().MobilePhone;

var obj = item.get_fieldValues().WorkPhone;
```

Check other properties at [How to get User Information using Javascript client object model or ECMA in SharePoint](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/15061.how-to-get-user-information-using-javascript-clientobject-model-or-ecma-in-share-point-2010.aspx)

---

**Also check**

- [Retrieve user profile properties by using the JavaScript object model in SharePoint](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/how-to-retrieve-user-profile-properties-by-using-the-javascript-object-model-in)
- [How to retrieve users profiles using JavaScript object model (JSOM) in SharePoint Online apps](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/206701/how-to-retrieve-users-profiles-using-javascript-object-model-jsom-in-sharepoin)

Answer (score 2):

We can easy achieve it using User Profile REST API and jQuery Ajax, add the code below into script editor web part in site page.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetMyProperties",
        headers: { Accept: "application/json;odata=verbose" },
        success: function (data) {
            var html="<p><img src='"+_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl+"/_layouts/15/userphoto.aspx?size=S&url="+data.d.PictureUrl+"&accountname=" + data.d.AccountName + "'/></p>";             
            html+="<p>UserName:"+data.d.DisplayName+"</p>";
            html+="<p>Email:"+data.d.Email+"</p>";
            $.each(data.d.UserProfileProperties.results,function(i,property){
                if(property.Key=="SPS-JobTitle"){
                    html+="<p>Job Title:"+property.Value+"</p>";
                }
            });
            $("#MyUserProfiles").html(html);
        },
        error: function (jQxhr, errorCode, errorThrown) {
            alert(errorThrown);
        }
    }); 
});
</script>
<div id="MyUserProfiles"/>
```

[image]